# What are wsm tables for?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

So I needed to migrate to a different hosting, I downloaded the database, import it to the new hosting database, and it would produce an error at

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`  AS  select `5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitId` AS `visitId`,`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime` AS `visitLastActionTime` from `5toy_wsm_pageViews` group by `5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitId` having (count(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`URLId`) = 1) ;
```

This was the error

> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

So in the sql file I deleted all of this:

```
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`  AS  select `5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitId` AS `visitId`,`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime` AS `visitLastActionTime` from `5toy_wsm_pageViews` group by `5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitId` having (count(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`URLId`) = 1) ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_dateWiseBounce`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_dateWiseBounce`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_dateWiseBounce`  AS  select date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `recordDate`,count(0) AS `bounce` from `5toy_wsm_bounceVisits` group by date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d') ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_dateWiseBounceRate`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_dateWiseBounceRate`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_dateWiseBounceRate`  AS  select `dwb`.`recordDate` AS `recordDate`,`dwb`.`bounce` AS `bounce`,`dwp`.`pageViews` AS `pageViews`,`dwv`.`visitors` AS `visitors`,((`dwb`.`bounce` / `dwp`.`pageViews`) * 100) AS `bRatePageViews`,((`dwb`.`bounce` / `dwv`.`visitors`) * 100) AS `bRateVisitors` from ((`5toy_wsm_dateWiseBounce` `dwb` left join `5toy_wsm_dateWisePageViews` `dwp` on((`dwb`.`recordDate` = `dwp`.`recordDate`))) left join `5toy_wsm_dateWiseVisitors` `dwv` on((`dwb`.`recordDate` = `dwv`.`recordDate`))) ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_dateWiseFirstVisitors`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_dateWiseFirstVisitors`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_dateWiseFirstVisitors`  AS  select date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`firstVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `recordDate`,count(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`visitorId`) AS `visitors` from `5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors` group by date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`firstVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d') ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_dateWisePageViews`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_dateWisePageViews`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_dateWisePageViews`  AS  select date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `recordDate`,sum(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`totalViews`) AS `pageViews` from `5toy_wsm_pageViews` group by date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d') ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_dateWiseVisitors`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_dateWiseVisitors`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_dateWiseVisitors`  AS  select date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS `recordDate`,count(0) AS `visitors` from `5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit` group by date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-%d') ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_hourWiseBounce`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_hourWiseBounce`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_hourWiseBounce`  AS  select hour(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00')) AS `hour`,count(0) AS `bounce` from `5toy_wsm_bounceVisits` where (convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00') >= '2021-01-22 00:00:00') group by hour(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00')) ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_hourWiseBounceRate`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_hourWiseBounceRate`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_hourWiseBounceRate`  AS  select `hwb`.`hour` AS `hour`,`hwb`.`bounce` AS `bounce`,`hwp`.`pageViews` AS `pageViews`,`hwv`.`visitors` AS `visitors`,((`hwb`.`bounce` / `hwp`.`pageViews`) * 100) AS `bRatePageViews`,((`hwb`.`bounce` / `hwv`.`visitors`) * 100) AS `bRateVisitors` from ((`5toy_wsm_hourWiseBounce` `hwb` left join `5toy_wsm_hourWisePageViews` `hwp` on((`hwb`.`hour` = `hwp`.`hour`))) left join `5toy_wsm_hourWiseVisitors` `hwv` on((`hwb`.`hour` = `hwv`.`hour`))) ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_hourWiseFirstVisitors`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_hourWiseFirstVisitors`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_hourWiseFirstVisitors`  AS  select hour(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`firstVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00')) AS `hour`,count(0) AS `visitors` from `5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors` where (convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`firstVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00') >= '2021-01-22 00:00:00') group by hour(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`firstVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00')) ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_hourWisePageViews`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_hourWisePageViews`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_hourWisePageViews`  AS  select hour(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00')) AS `hour`,sum(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`totalViews`) AS `pageViews` from `5toy_wsm_pageViews` where (convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00') >= '2021-01-22 00:00:00') group by hour(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00')) ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_hourWiseVisitors`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_hourWiseVisitors`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_hourWiseVisitors`  AS  select hour(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit`.`firstActionVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00')) AS `hour`,count(0) AS `visitors` from `5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit` where (convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit`.`firstActionVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00') >= '2021-01-22 00:00:00') group by hour(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit`.`firstActionVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00')) ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_monthWiseBounce`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_monthWiseBounce`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_monthWiseBounce`  AS  select date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m') AS `recordMonth`,count(0) AS `bounce` from `5toy_wsm_bounceVisits` group by date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_bounceVisits`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m-') ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_monthWiseBounceRate`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_monthWiseBounceRate`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_monthWiseBounceRate`  AS  select `mwb`.`recordMonth` AS `recordMonth`,`mwb`.`bounce` AS `bounce`,`mwp`.`pageViews` AS `pageViews`,`mwv`.`visitors` AS `visitors`,((`mwb`.`bounce` / `mwp`.`pageViews`) * 100) AS `bRatePageViews`,((`mwb`.`bounce` / `mwv`.`visitors`) * 100) AS `bRateVisitors` from ((`5toy_wsm_monthWiseBounce` `mwb` left join `5toy_wsm_monthWisePageViews` `mwp` on((`mwb`.`recordMonth` = `mwp`.`recordMonth`))) left join `5toy_wsm_monthWiseVisitors` `mwv` on((`mwb`.`recordMonth` = `mwv`.`recordMonth`))) ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_monthWiseFirstVisitors`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_monthWiseFirstVisitors`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_monthWiseFirstVisitors`  AS  select date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`firstVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m') AS `recordMonth`,count(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`visitorId`) AS `visitors` from `5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors` group by date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`.`firstVisitTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m') ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_monthWisePageViews`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_monthWisePageViews`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_monthWisePageViews`  AS  select date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m') AS `recordMonth`,sum(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`totalViews`) AS `pageViews` from `5toy_wsm_pageViews` group by date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_pageViews`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m') ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_monthWiseVisitors`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_monthWiseVisitors`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_monthWiseVisitors`  AS  select date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m') AS `recordMonth`,count(0) AS `visitors` from `5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit` group by date_format(convert_tz(`5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit`.`visitLastActionTime`,'+00:00','+00:00'),'%Y-%m') ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_pageViews`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_pageViews`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_pageViews`  AS  select `LV`.`visitId` AS `visitId`,`LV`.`URLId` AS `URLId`,`LV`.`keyword` AS `keyword`,`LV`.`refererUrlId` AS `refererUrlId`,`LU`.`countryId` AS `countryId`,`LU`.`regionId` AS `regionId`,count(0) AS `totalViews`,max(`LV`.`serverTime`) AS `visitLastActionTime` from (`5toy_wsm_logVisit` `LV` left join `5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit` `LU` on((`LV`.`visitId` = `LU`.`id`))) group by `LV`.`visitId`,`LV`.`URLId` ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_uniqueVisitors`  AS  select `LU`.`id` AS `id`,`LU`.`visitorId` AS `visitorId`,sum(`LU`.`totalTimeVisit`) AS `totalTimeVisit`,min(`LV`.`serverTime`) AS `firstVisitTime`,`LU`.`refererUrlId` AS `refererUrlId` from (`5toy_wsm_logUniqueVisit` `LU` left join `5toy_wsm_logVisit` `LV` on((`LV`.`visitId` = `LU`.`id`))) group by `LU`.`visitorId` ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `5toy_wsm_visitorInfo`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `5toy_wsm_visitorInfo`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mbluhiqcygcjvfgk`@`10.%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `5toy_wsm_visitorInfo`  AS  select `LV`.`
```

And it worked, it imported succesfully but im worried that it might broke something, I had a traffic/visitors plugin my best bet is that it was the data from that plugin, if it is, it doesnt matter. But if `wsm` means `woocommerce stock manager` that seems important

Comment: The 'BouceRate' bit would lead me to believe it's some sort of analytics plugin, not sure why WooCommerce Stock Manager would track Bounce Rates.  Can you look in the SQL file and see what that data is?